# Bridge specific topic or except bridge topic with ros2 ros1_bridge

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the tutorial of [ros1_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge)

I can bridge the ros1 topics to ros2 and worked very well.

And I want to use this feature to communicate between multi-robots through DDS

But there is a problem with bridging **big_data** like image_raw when I use `--bridge-all-topics`

It will cause the network traffic jams

Is it possible to bridge specific topic or just except some topics that I don't want it bridged to ros2?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329834/bridge-specific-topic-or-except-bridge-topic-with-ros2-ros1_bridge/) by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-08-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-08-01**:
Which bridge executable are you currently using? There are different ones for different use cases: `dynamic_bridge`, `parameter_bridge`, `static_bridge`, ...

**Comment by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on 2019-08-01**:
@Dirk Thomas I use dynamic_bridge. I have no idea about other methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you dig into the [ros1_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge) source code you will find the answer. 
[dynamic_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/src/dynamic_bridge.cpp) has the following available flags that are of interest in this case:

```
--bridge-all-topics: Bridge all topics in both directions, whether or not there is a matching subscriber.
--bridge-all-1to2-topics: Bridge all ROS 1 topics to ROS 2, whether or not there is a matching subscriber.
--bridge-all-2to1-topics: Bridge all ROS 2 topics to ROS 1, whether or not there is a matching subscriber.
```

Regarding your question for bridging specific topics you should look at the [parameter_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/src/parameter_bridge.cpp):

```
bridge all topics listed in a ROS 1 parameter. The parameter needs to be an array and each item needs to be a dictionary with the following keys; 
topic: the name of the topic to bridge
type: the type of the topic to bridge
queue_size: the queue size to use (default: 100)
```

or [static_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/src/static_bridge.cpp) which gives an example implementation of bridging one topic.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on 2019-08-02**:
Thank you for your reply. And yes, I found the solution after I review the source code of ros1_bridge. Now, I feel so sorry about I did not try to look into ros1_bridge. Thank you so much!